# using jquery to set params in grails

Tags: jquery, grails

I am trying to get some params on a `g:remoteLink` with jQuery.

GSP:

```
<g:remoteLink name="newCat" action="wizard" method="GET" params="" update="updateMe">
     test
</g:remoteLink>
```

JavaScript:

```
var test = "test";
$("#newCat").attr("params", 'sel=' + test);
```

This way doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your forgot to add `id="newCat"`.

Change your remoteLink code to:

```
<g:remoteLink id="newCat" name="newCat" action="wizard" method="GET" params="" update="updateMe">
     test
</g:remoteLink>
```